# Using Razor to get HTML from Resource File

Tags: html, .net, razor

I am storing this string within a ResourceFile:

```
Please select a @Html.ActionLink("Personal", "PersonalAccount", "Help"), 
or a @Html.ActionLink("Corporate", "BusinessAccount", "Help") account.
```

Now I want to put this content on a `Span` element inside the `Title` attribute.

I tried this without success :

```
 <span class="tooltip-icon tooltip" 
       title="@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ToolTips.AccountType))">
 </span>
```

***The issue is that I am seeing the regular text, not the content encoded.***

Comment: Can you show what your seeing and what the expected result should be?  Perhaps it's just me, but, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I am doing this to get that text to appear as a Title Tooltip with Jquery (Tooltipster implementation). What I am seeing on the Tooltip is actually the string that I have inside the Resource file : `Please select a @Html.ActionLink("Personal", "PersonalAccount", "Help"), or a @Html.ActionLink("Corporate", "BusinessAccount", "Help") account.` instead of that same string but HTML encoded, so that Razor generate the <a> tag's accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is not going to double parse your page, It parses your page and renders the content of your resource which is a text having @ in it(Please select a `@Html.ActionLink("Personal", "PersonalAccount", "Help")).` It doesn't care what is in the resource.

Any how, you can't do it this way and you shouldn't, the only culture specific part of your code is the link's text which you should just put that part in your resource file not whole of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Using VahidND suggestion I was able to do it without **Razor** inside the Resource file.

So I actually ended with this :

```
<span class="tooltip-icon tooltip" 
    title="@String.Format(ToolTips.PTAccountTypeRadio1,
    Html.ActionLink(ToolTips.PTAccountTypeRadio2, "PersonalAccount", "Help"), 
    Html.ActionLink(ToolTips.PTAccountTypeRadio3, "BusinessAccount", "Help"))"
</span>
```